# Toggle array value on a index on button click Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array and i want to toggle its value on 0 index on button click
between 'x' and 'a' but this is not working.I can not understand what i am doing wrong i am new in JavaScript.

```js
function toggle() {
    let array = ['x', 'r', 'r'];
    let i = 0;
    if (array[i] == 'a') {
        array[i] = 'x';
    }
    else {
        array[i] = 'a';
    }

    console.log(array)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='toggle()'>Toggle</button>
```

expected output

```
["a", "r", "a"]
["x", "r", "a"]
["a", "r", "a"]
["x", "r", "a"]
```

but got

```
["a", "r", "a"]
["a", "r", "a"]
["a", "r", "a"]
["a", "r", "a"]
```

Comment: Move `let array = ['x', 'r', 'r'];` outside the function. Your current code is recreating the array anew each time the function runs.

Comment: how can i do same thing in react using state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2):

Declare the array outside of `toggle`, so that changes to it can be observed over multiple calls of `toggle`:

```js
const array = ['x', 'r', 'r'];

function toggle() {
  let i = 0;
  if (array[i] == 'a') {
    array[i] = 'x';
  } else {
    array[i] = 'a';
  }

  console.log(array)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='toggle()'>Toggle</button>
```

Otherwise, you'll be creating a *new* array containing `['x', 'r', 'r']` on every call, so it'll change the first element from an `x` to an `x` and log `["a", "r", "a"]` every time.